# eigenvalues and matrices kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let B be an n × n matrix with eigenvalue λ. Note that Eλ(B) can be written as Ker(B −
λIn). Show that Ker(B − λIn) ⊆ Ker((B − λIn)^2). Please help.
Eλ(B)is the eigenspace associated with eigenvalue λ.
In is the identity matrix for nxn matrix

Comment: For any matrix $M$, if $Mx = 0$ then what can you say about $M^2x$?

Comment: What does $E\lambda(B)$ denote ? Also, what is $\lambda In$ ? Can you please specify what these notations mean ?

Comment: @Kolmogorov - I'm guessing the notation is intended to be $E_{\lambda}(B)$ (a somewhat common notation for the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$), and $I_n$ (the $n \times n$ identity matrix). But certainly these should be defined in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity $M=B-\lambda I_n$:
$$v \in Ker(M) \Rightarrow Mv=0 \Rightarrow MMv=M0 \Rightarrow M^2v=0 \Rightarrow v \in Ker(M^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then

$Bv=\lambda v$  and $v\in Ker(B-\lambda I)$

we want to prove that $Ker(B − λIn) ⊆ Ker((B − λIn)^2)$ which means

$v \in Ker(B − λIn)$ $\Rightarrow$ $v\in Ker((B − λIn)^2)$

$(B − λI)^2=B^2-2\lambda B+ \lambda^2I$

$(B − λI)^2v=B^2v-2\lambda Bv+ \lambda^2Iv=\lambda^2v-2\lambda^2v+\lambda^2v=0$ which means

$v\in  Ker((B − λIn)^2)$ so  $Ker(B − λIn) ⊆ Ker((B − λIn)^2)$